# How to enable FINE logging for a single java class

Tags: java, logging

I'm using [`java.util.logging.Logger`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) logging in my program.  How do I enable `FINE` logging for a single class, while setting it to `WARNING` for every other class?

I'd prefer to do this programatically in my `main()` method rather than needing to set up additional properties files.

Comment: Basically the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470430/java-util-logging-logger-doesnt-respect-java-util-logging-level .

Answer (score 2):

I know the OP has asked to do this programatically but here's an example of how to do it in the properties file too.

*Caveat: I thought it was worthy of inclusion as the header doesn't indicate programatically and many developers will want to manage it through the logging.properties. Also there isn't really a lot on-line about this, it can be confusing and is slightly different to, say log4j*

The root logging level is indicated by the `.level` config. This dictates which events are by default to be captured and "distributed for" logging. The root logging level is the level used by the "root logger" in the logging hierarchy. See [this onjava article for more info on the logging hierarchy](https://web.archive.org/web/20170912024236/http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/06/19/log.html?page=2).

Below, the root log level is set to WARNING so will ordinarily capture only WARNING events. This is inherited by all child loggers in the hierarchy, unless you configure otherwise (later):

```
.level=WARNING
```

This root-logging level only indicates what is captured, not what is "distributed". How a captured event (message) is distributed is down to the handlers associated with the logger. For instance, a ConsoleHandler will output the event to the console. For instance:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = WARNING
```

This ConsoleHandler.level indicates the level for which this handler should distribute - or print - the message. So, if a FINE message is received with the above config then this handler will not print it. It will print any messages with a WARNING log level or above though.

Setting to ALL will ensure that the ConsoleHandler will print all messages to the console (an we also need to configure the root level to ensure all are captured):

```
.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
```

However, this would create a lot of noise which we also don't want. So, to reduce the FINE-level events to those classes we're interested in, we change the logging level of those specific loggers only:

```
com.level = WARNING
com.mypackage.MyClass1.level = FINE
com.mypackage.MyClass2.level = FINE
com.mypackage.mysubpackage.MyClass3.level = FINE
```

Note that in the above, I've explicitly set the level for the "com" logger to WARNING.

Comment: Won't `com.mypackage` inherit `com` and still be restricted to WARNING level?

Comment: "... the properties file ...".  Which properties file is this referring to?

Comment: @tresf, `logging.properties` is where you normally configure your logging config. Cursory search on "java.util.logging.Logger properties file" presented this concise guide: https://mkyong.com/logging/logging-properties-example/ (2021).

Comment: @Nyerguds, yes , `WARNING` would be inherited by all child loggers in the hierarchy. In the example I'm reconfiguring only for specific classes of interest. Note the OP was asking for specific class-level logging. (Sorry for long delay, I didn't notice this comment).

Comment: @wmorrison365 thanks for the follow-up. I understand this answer was written a long time ago however the solution should include all the necessary information needed.  In your own words "there isn't really a lot online about this".  The answer would be more complete if it offered this information.

Answer (score 1):

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).setLevel(Level.FINE);
```

Comment: That's close, but doesn't work for two reasons:
1) I want to be able to put the the code in my main class, so not all users of my utility class have to see the FINE logging.
2) It seems that even if I do what you suggested the handler is still swallowing  all my FINE messages.

Comment: `setLevel(...)` returns void, this example has syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to have a logger defined for every single class in question but rather want to share loggers between classes, you can alternatively implement your own java.util.logging.Handler that has its own way of filtering for class names using the information provided by LogRecord.getSourceClassName().

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can set your log level for your `Handler` and your specific class `Logger` to FINE, while keeping all the other `Logger`s for the rest of your code base to WARNING should do the trick.  Both the `Logger` and the `Handler` need to pass the level filter for a message to be logged.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a method I added to my mail class that's actually working.  I would still welcome any improvements from others.

```
private static void setupLogging() {
  // To enable FINE logging in a single class, apparently this bewildering
  // maze of statements is required.
  Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.FINE);
  for (Handler handler : Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers()) {
    handler.setLevel(Level.FINE);
  }
  MyOtherClass.logger.setLevel(Level.FINE);
  Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
}
```