# Removing a log from Spring Security authentication logging

Tags: spring-security

In AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.class we have a method AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate, a BadCredentialsException is thrown if the username is not found:

```
    try {
        user = retrieveUser(username, (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication);
    } catch (UsernameNotFoundException notFound) {
        ***logger.debug("User '" + username + "' not found");***

        if (hideUserNotFoundExceptions) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                    "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        } else {
            throw notFound;
        }
    }
```

What to do in case I don't want to log the error message logger.debug("User '" + username + "' not found") as it is a security vulnerability (if a user accidentally enters password in username then it gets logged).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when you run your application in production you shouldn't run with the overall logging level to `debug`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031209/1258079) about which ones to use.

However, you could configure the logging level of this class to be something less verbose than `debug`, like `info`. This way it wouldn't log the `User x not found` entry.

To set log levels of individual classes (implementation dependant), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18510111/1258079).