# Why are the Level.FINE logging messages not showing?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

The [JavaDocs for `java.util.logging.Level`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Level.html) state:

---

The levels in descending order are:

- `SEVERE` (highest value)
- `WARNING`
- `INFO`
- `CONFIG`
- `FINE`
- `FINER`
- `FINEST` (lowest value)

---

### Source

```
import java.util.logging.*;

class LoggingLevelsBlunder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
        logger.setLevel(Level.FINER);
        System.out.println("Logging level is: " + logger.getLevel());
        for (int ii=0; ii<3; ii++) {
            logger.log(Level.FINE, ii + " " + (ii*ii));
            logger.log(Level.INFO, ii + " " + (ii*ii));
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
Logging level is: FINER
Jun 11, 2011 9:39:23 PM LoggingLevelsBlunder main
INFO: 0 0
Jun 11, 2011 9:39:24 PM LoggingLevelsBlunder main
INFO: 1 1
Jun 11, 2011 9:39:24 PM LoggingLevelsBlunder main
INFO: 2 4
Press any key to continue . . .
```

### Problem statement

My example sets the `Level` to `FINER`, so I was expecting to see 2 messages for each loop.  Instead I see a single message for each loop (the `Level.FINE` messages are missing).

### Question

What needs changing in order to see the `FINE` (, `FINER` or `FINEST`) output?

### Update (solution)

Thanks to [Vineet Reynolds' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315699/why-are-my-level-fine-logging-messages-not-showing/6315736#6315736), this version works according to my expectation.  It displays 3 x `INFO` messages, & 3 x `FINE` messages.

```
import java.util.logging.*;

class LoggingLevelsBlunder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
        // LOG this level to the log
        logger.setLevel(Level.FINER);

        ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
        // PUBLISH this level
        handler.setLevel(Level.FINER);
        logger.addHandler(handler);

        System.out.println("Logging level is: " + logger.getLevel());
        for (int ii=0; ii<3; ii++) {
            logger.log(Level.FINE, ii + " " + (ii*ii));
            logger.log(Level.INFO, ii + " " + (ii*ii));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to me that you will have the messages printed twice on the console for INFO and above: first by the anonymous logger, then by its parent, the global logger which also has a ConsoleHandler set to INFO by default. To disable the global logger, you need to add this line of code: logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);

Comment: I just want to confirm mins comment about the doubles.  you will get two outputs unless you use .setUseParentHandlers(false);

Comment: In your solution, **logger** has two Handlers (one default at INFO and one added at FINE), so logger.info("something") would print twice

Comment: What is point of adding a logging properties file and setting configuration if everything at the end is governed by root logger only? @andrew-thompson

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Loggers only log the message, i.e. they create the log records (or logging requests). They do not publish the messages to the destinations, which is taken care of by the Handlers. Setting the level of a logger, only causes it to *create* log records matching that level or higher.

You might be using a [`ConsoleHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html) (I couldn't infer where your output is System.err or a file, but I would assume that it is the former), which defaults to publishing log records of the level `Level.INFO`. You will have to configure this handler, to publish log records of level `Level.FINER` and higher, for the desired outcome.

I would recommend reading the [Java Logging Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html) guide, in order to understand the underlying design. The guide covers the difference between the concept of a Logger and a Handler.

**Editing the handler level**

***1. Using the Configuration file***

The java.util.logging properties file (by default, this is the `logging.properties` file in `JRE_HOME/lib`) can be modified to change the default level of the ConsoleHandler:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINER
```

***2. Creating handlers at runtime***

This is not recommended, for it would result in overriding the global configuration. Using this throughout your code base will result in a possibly unmanageable logger configuration.

```
Handler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.FINER);
Logger.getAnonymousLogger().addHandler(consoleHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks.  That did the trick.  I realize now why I was initially so confused.  I had previously worked with logging levels, but my implementation at that time simply dropped every logged message into a list that was displayed with no regard to the `Handler`.

Comment: You're welcome. And yeah, the design does get to you, if one has been writing loggers that simply dumped strings into a file, console etc.

Comment: And changing the logging.properties in the global JRE library is manageable?

Comment: Please note, that the level of logger itself must be less restrictive, than handler's level. Before logging Java checks the maximum level between logger and handler. So if you set only handler.setLevel(Level.FINER); you will see nothing because the default logger level is Level.INFO. You must set it to FINER, FINEST or ALL. Say logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);

Comment: I guess this will solve the problem as a one-liner, even when you use anonymous and named loggers in a default environment: `Logger.getGlobal().getParent().getHandlers()[0].setLevel(Level.FINER);`

Answer (score 33):

**The Why**

java.util.logging has a root logger that defaults to `Level.INFO`, and a ConsoleHandler attached to it that also defaults to `Level.INFO`.
`FINE` is lower than `INFO`, so fine messages are not displayed by default.

---

**Solution 1**

Create a logger for your whole application, e.g. from your package name or use [`Logger.getGlobal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getGlobal()), and hook your own ConsoleLogger to it.
Then either ask root logger to shut up (to avoid duplicate output of higher level messages), or ask your logger to [not forward logs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getUseParentHandlers()) to root.

```java
public static final Logger applog = Logger.getGlobal();
...

// Create and set handler
Handler systemOut = new ConsoleHandler();
systemOut.setLevel( Level.ALL );
applog.addHandler( systemOut );
applog.setLevel( Level.ALL );

// Prevent logs from processed by default Console handler.
applog.setUseParentHandlers( false ); // Solution 1
Logger.getLogger("").setLevel( Level.OFF ); // Solution 2
```

---

**Solution 2**

Alternatively, you may lower the root logger's bar.

You can set them by code:

```java
Logger rootLog = Logger.getLogger("");
rootLog.setLevel( Level.FINE );
rootLog.getHandlers()[0].setLevel( Level.FINE ); // Default console handler
```

Or with logging configuration file, if you are [using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960099/how-to-set-up-java-logging-using-a-properties-file-java-util-logging):

```
.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
```

By lowering the global level, you may start seeing messages from core libraries, such as from some Swing or JavaFX components.
In this case you may set a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Filter.html) on the root logger to filter out messages not from your program.

Comment: applog.setUseParentHandlers( false ) these code help me ,thanks so much.

Comment: Thank you for specifying that the level should be changed both in the root logger and in the console handler!

Answer (score 13):

**WHY**

As mentioned by @Sheepy, the reason why it doesn't work is that `java.util.logging.Logger` has a root logger that defaults to `Level.INFO`, and the `ConsoleHandler` attached to that root logger also defaults to `Level.INFO`. Therefore, in order to see the `FINE` (, `FINER` or `FINEST`) output, you need to set the default value of the root logger and its `ConsoleHandler` to `Level.FINE` as follows:

```
Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.FINE);
Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers()[0].setLevel(Level.FINE);
```

**The problem of your Update (solution)**

As mentioned by @mins, you will have the messages printed twice on the console for `INFO` and above: first by the anonymous logger, then by its parent, the root logger which also has a `ConsoleHandler` set to `INFO` by default. To disable the root logger, you need to add this line of code: `logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);`

There are other ways to prevent logs from being processed by default Console handler of the root logger mentioned by @Sheepy, e.g.:

```
Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers()[0].setLevel( Level.OFF );
```

But `Logger.getLogger("").setLevel( Level.OFF );` won't work because it only blocks the message passed directly to the root logger, not the message comes from a child logger. To illustrate how the `Logger Hierarchy` works, I draw the following diagram:

[image]

[`public void setLevel(Level newLevel)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setLevel(java.util.logging.Level)) set the log level specifying which message levels will be logged by this logger. Message levels lower than this value will be discarded. The level value Level.OFF can be used to turn off logging. If the new level is null, it means that this node should inherit its level from its nearest ancestor with a specific (non-null) level value.

Answer (score 4):

[why is my java logging not working](http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/javaGuiTips/javaLoggingDebugging.html)

provides a jar file that will help you work out why your logging in not working as expected.
It gives you a complete dump of what loggers and handlers have been installed and what levels are set and at which level in the logging hierarchy.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tried other variants, this can be proper

```
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());        
    Level level = Level.ALL;
    for(Handler h : java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers())    
        h.setLevel(level);
    logger.setLevel(level);
// this must be shown
    logger.fine("fine");
    logger.info("info");
```

Comment: This answer and Joe Yichong's point out that the logger first gets the log message, but then passes the message up the chain to the *handlers*.  This is confusing but works OK in practice.  The upshot is that most handlers are actually at the root level so they can be controlled more easily by an operator.  The technique of grabbing the root logger and setting all of its handlers is what I do when I need to control logging in a program (which you normally should NOT do).

Answer (score 0):

I found my actual problem and it was not mentioned in any answer: some of my unit-tests were causing logging initialization code to be run multiple times within the same test suite, messing up the logging on the later tests.

Answer (score 0):

This solution appears better to me, regarding maintainability and design for change:

1. Create the logging property file embedding it in the resource project folder, to be included in the jar file:

   ```
   # Logging
   handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
   .level = ALL

   # Console Logging
   java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
   ```
2. Load the property file from code:

   ```
   public static java.net.URL retrieveURLOfJarResource(String resourceName) {
      return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resourceName);
   }

   public synchronized void initializeLogger() {
      try (InputStream is = retrieveURLOfJarResource("logging.properties").openStream()) {
         LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(is);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         // ...
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**To change the logcat level:**

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.<YOUR_LOG_TAG> <LEVEL>
```

For example:

```
C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe shell setprop log.tag.com.mycompany.myapp VERBOSE
```

**Here is why this works for Logger:**

The root logger, which is the parent of your logger, is using an internal logging handler `com.android.internal.logging.AndroidHandler`. This handler in its `publish` method is checking [Log.isLoggable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log#isLoggable(java.lang.String,%20int)) and writing to Log.

**Note about <YOUR_LOG_TAG>:**

Basically this is the name of your Logger. For global Logger it is `Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME`. For anonymous logger it is `"null"`. Tag is limited to 23 characters.

`AndroidHandler` does a transformation from the logger name to the tag:

```java
    private static String loggerNameToTag(String loggerName) {
        // Anonymous logger.
        if (loggerName == null) {
            return "null";
        }

        int length = loggerName.length();
        if (length <= 23) {
            return loggerName;
        }

        int lastPeriod = loggerName.lastIndexOf(".");
        return length - (lastPeriod + 1) <= 23
                ? loggerName.substring(lastPeriod + 1)
                : loggerName.substring(loggerName.length() - 23);
    }
```