# Run minmal Spring Boot test with enabled selected factory/processor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-logback

To the testing of logging I need to activate `LogbackLoggingSystem` processor or corresponding factory:

```
# Logging Systems
org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystemFactory=\
org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.Factory,\
org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem.Factory,\
org.springframework.boot.logging.java.JavaLoggingSystem.Factory
```

I wrote a test:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
        initializers = {ConfigDataApplicationContextInitializer.class})
@Slf4j
public class MyAppTest {
    @Test
    void my() {
        log.info("OK");
    }
}
```

I want Spring Boot activates JUL to Slf4j redirection during the test. There is a magical call `SLF4JBridgeHandler.install()` which I want to have set before the test.

**UPDATE** Seems `LoggingSystemFactory` is instantiated via `LoggingApplicationListener`, so the alternative question is: how can I specify `LoggingApplicationListener` to be used in Spring Test context.

**UPDATE 2** I archived a different goal - configuration of JUL logging on app startup a different way - via system property `java.util.logging.config.class`, see [Setting java.util.logging.config.file at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306014/setting-java-util-logging-config-file-at-runtime/77222638#77222638) This solution is Spring independent, also it doesn't pollute `main()` or `@Configuration`, but requires extra property on command line.