# Java Logging (utils) issue with Levels

Tags: java, logging

I had a problem with java.util.logging stuff... I was unable to log fine, finer and finest levels.

I've found ideal solution here:
[Why are the Level.FINE logging messages not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315699/why-are-my-level-fine-logging-messages-not-showing)

I have created my own class for getting appropriate logger instances:

```
public static Logger getLogger(Level level, String name) {
        Logger logger;
        logger = (name != null) ? Logger.getLogger(name) : Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
        logger.setLevel(level);
        ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
        handler.setLevel(level);
        logger.addHandler(handler);

        return logger;
    }
```

But after using it my logger logs each level twice:

```
private static final Logger logger = testlogger.getLogger(Level.INFO, "testname");
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Uuuuu!!!");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Something wrong");
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Something wrong");
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Something wrong");
            logger.log(Level.CONFIG, "Something wrong");
            logger.log(Level.FINE, "Something wrong");
            logger.log(Level.FINER, "Something wrong");
            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Something wrong");
        } 
    }
```

Output:

> 08.07.2013 09:37:08 xxx.testclass main SCHWERWIEGEND: Something wrong
>   08.07.2013 09:37:08 xxx.testclass main SCHWERWIEGEND: Something wrong
>   08.07.2013 09:37:08 xxx.testclass main WARNUNG: Something wrong
>   08.07.2013 09:37:08 xxx.testclass main WARNUNG: Something wrong
>   08.07.2013 09:37:08 xxx.testclass main INFO: Something wrong
>   08.07.2013 09:37:08 xxx.testclass main INFO: Something wrong

I'm guessing, Logger has some default handlers added, so I've tried:

```
for (Handler h : logger.getHandlers()) {
            logger.removeHandler(h);
        }
```

before adding ConsoleHanlder, but with no result.

From the post I've mentioned, I understand that in order to display fine, finer, finest levels I have to add ConsoleHandler.

So my question is "How can I force logger to use only ConsoleHandler" ?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Java Util Logging before but base on my experience in Log4J/SLF4J, your way of using JUL seems strange.

We don't setup the handler and logger's level every time we get the logger.  Normally it is one-time setup before the application run.  So that JUL already have the logger hierarchy setup correctly, and you are simply getting the logger you want to use and do your logging.

The way you do the setup is going to cause big trouble too, because you will add a new ConsoleHandler every time you get the same logger.  That means, if you get it 10 times, the logger you got from the 10th time, each logging will cause 10 message to display on screen.

Come back to your problem, I believe the root logger in JUL is setup with a ConsoleHandler by default.  That means, you don't really need to setup the ConsoleHandler by yourself, because each logger will follow its parent's handler, which is in turn following root logger's handler.

Either remove your ConsoleHandler setup in your code and follow parent's handler.  Or you may change the additivity of your logger to false (something like `logger.setUseParentHandlers(false)` in JUL).

However, my recommendation is to get some basic understandings on JUL and know how it should be used first.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for these tips! My implementation is just an extremely fast demo. Of course I don't want use it in this way exactly. The issue with ParentHadlers was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.