# java.util.logging: setting the log level dynamically

Tags: java, netbeans, java.util.logging

I'm trying the following code example (based on code from [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaLogging.html)). My aim is to set the level of the logging from run time.

```
package logchecker;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Logchecker {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logchecker.class.getName());

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("This logger's level is " + logger.getLevel());   // null
      logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
      System.out.println("This logger's level is " + logger.getLevel());   // null
      logger.info("TEST");
      logger.finest("FINEST TEST");
   }
}
```

The output is:

> This logger's level is null
>
> This logger's level is ALL
>
> Sep 17, 2013 1:46:31 PM logchecker.Logchecker main
>
> INFO: TEST

It obviously doesn't output the `log.finest`.
What am I missing?
I'm running with NetBeans 7.3.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315699/why-are-my-level-fine-logging-messages-not-showing) question on SO can help you.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315699/why-are-my-level-fine-logging-messages-not-showing?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to set my Handlers level as well. Added the following code to my main:

```
Logger root = Logger.getLogger("");
Handler[] handlers = root.getHandlers();
for(Handler h: handlers){
    h.setLevel(Level.INFO);
}
```

Of course you can set the level to whatever you need.

thanks again to the comments for directing me to the solution