# Java logging does not seem to work for FINE / FINER / FINEST levels

Tags: java, logging

I am using `java.util.logging` to perform logging at different levels. My problem is that I can't get the levels `FINE` / `FINER` / `FINEST` to show any output. I have seen a similar thread ([Why are the Level.FINE logging messages not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315699/why-are-the-level-fine-logging-messages-not-showing)) which does not seem to solve my problem though. I have the following main class:

```
package logtest;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {


    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.info("info");
        LOGGER.severe("severe");
        LOGGER.fine("fine");
    }

}
```

in a file `src/logtest/Main.java` and a file `logging.properties` in the root directory of my project:

```
.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

I execute the generated binary (in `bin/logtest`) like this:

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -classpath bin logtest.Main
```

and I get this result (observe that the `FINE` message is missing):

```
Aug 05, 2015 6:13:04 PM logtest.Main main
INFO: info
Aug 05, 2015 6:13:04 PM logtest.Main main
SEVERE: severe
```

Interestingly, if I change the entry `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level` to `SEVERE` the first message disappears:

```
Aug 05, 2015 6:14:09 PM logtest.Main main
SEVERE: severe
```

So I know the file is read and interpreted correctly. But I just can't get the `FINE` logging message to show up on the console (using openjdk-8 btw). Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have changed the level on the handler, but not the logger.  You'll need to do both.

You could do this in code:

```
LOGGER.setLevel(Level.FINE);
```

Or, you can read the settings from your properties file.  To modify the default logging level, you can add:

```
.level=FINE
```

You can specify the logging levels for your own loggers by adding lines such as

```
com.mycompany.myapp.level=FINE
```