# JTable repeats one row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I created a `JTable` and inserted the column header and data into the table.

- `data` is vector of vectors
- `column_header` is vector of string

This is the code:

```
Vector<Diagnosis_data> Arraylist_object = new Vector<Diagnosis_data>();
Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

Diagnosis_data d1 = new Diagnosis_data("92992","1",1422-09-09,1422-09-18,E11.9,"Type 2 diabetes mellitus without complications");
Diagnosis_data d2 = new Diagnosis_data("8199111","2",1415-09-09,1415-09-18,E11.622,"Type 2 diabetes mellitus with other skin ulcer");

Arraylist_object.add(d1);
Arraylist_object.add(d2);

int f = 0;
while(f < Arraylist_object.size())
{
    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();

    for(; f < Arraylist_object.size() ; f++)
    {
        vector.add(Arraylist_object.get(f).patient_ID);
        vector.add(Arraylist_object.get(f).Ad_ID);
        vector.add(Arraylist_object.get(f).Ad_start);
        vector.add(Arraylist_object.get(f).Ad_End);
        vector.add(Arraylist_object.get(f).Diagnosis_code);
        vector.add(Arraylist_object.get(f).Diagnosis_Des);

        data.add(vector);
    }
}


DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data,column_header);

JTable table_2 = new JTable(tableModel);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table_2);

scrollPane.setBounds(1, 1, 1050, 500);
panel_1.add(scrollPane);
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Obviously (I hope) remove all the unrelated cruft at the top of the GUI. 2) You've described a problem, but asked no question. What is your question? 3) `scrollPane.setBounds(1, 1, 1050, 500);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, ..

Comment: .. or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: *"my answer is edited to reflect the added code"* I suggested to post an MCVE / SSCCE. What didn't you understand?

Comment: @AndrewThompson  what should **_I_** understand? Why should **_I_** post an MCVE/SSCCE as ANSWER? I edited the question, but I am not the author...

Comment: anyway, seems like the problem is already solve since the author is already asking about layout in another question (with correct data)

Comment: No, post the problem code (in the form of an MCVE / SSCCE) as part of the *question*, like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315699/why-are-the-level-fine-logging-messages-not-showing) ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson **I AM NOT the author of the question**, I just edited it!!! I have no "problem code" to post... The author is "monaalhumud"

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Oh, my bad. No, I don't expect someone providing an answer to post an MCVE/SSCCE, but confused you with the OP.  :P

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted is working given the correct data - the problem must be the data. Use a debugger to check it or, just for testing, print out the content of `data`.

Probably the same Vector is being added to `data` multiple times or the content of each Vector is same *(maybe the Patient object is using `static` fields?)*

Note: data I used to test your code - a new Vector must be created for each row:

```
Vector<Vector<?>> data = new Vector<>();
Vector<String> column_header = new Vector<>();

column_header.addAll(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));

Vector<String> row;
row = new Vector<>();
row.addAll(Arrays.asList("11", "12", "13"));
data.add(row);
row = new Vector<>();
row.addAll(Arrays.asList("21", "22", "23"));
data.add(row);
row = new Vector<>();
row.addAll(Arrays.asList("31", "32", "33"));
data.add(row);
```

*EDIT*: After the generating `data` code has been added, it is clear that the problem is, as I suspected above: "the same Vector is being added".

Look at this part:

```
Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();

for(; f < Arraylist_object.size() ; f++)
{
    vector.add(...);

    data.add(vector);
}
```

The `vector` is created only once OUTSIDE the loop, but being added multiple time inside the loop.

Solution: create the vector INSIDE the loop

And there is no need for the additional `while`, actually the convention is to declare the variable in the `for` loop (and use `i` as counter):

```
for(int i = 0; i < Arraylist_object.size() ; i++)
{
    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();

    vector.add(Arraylist_object.get(i).patient_ID);
    ...

    data.add(vector);
}
```

or use `foreach`:

```
for (Diagnosis_data diagnosis : Arraylist_object)
{
    Vector<Object> vector = ...
    vector.add(diagnosis.patient_ID);
    vector.add(diagnosis.Ad_ID);
    ...
}
```

**Advice**: spend some time learning to use a debugger, it will not be wasted if you want to do serious programming.

**Advice2**: as commented by Andrew Thompson, use `LayoutManager`'s instead of using constant coordinates to layout your components. Tutorial: [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Dear Carlos - thenk you so much for your replay .. i test data by printing it it is contains a good vectors with the same sort ... this is the code for filling vector

Comment: <i> int f = 0;
   while(f < Arraylist_object.size())
   {
    Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();

    for(; f < Arraylist_object.size() ; f++)
    {
     vector.add(Arraylist_object.get(f).patient_ID);
      vector.add(Arraylist_object.get(f).Ad_ID);
      vector.add(Arraylist_object.get(f).Ad_start);
      vector.add(Arraylist_object.get(f).Ad_End);
      vector.add(Arraylist_object.get(f).Diagnosis_code);
      vector.add(Arraylist_object.get(f).Diagnosis_Des);
     
   
     data.add(vector);

    }
   }
   </i>

Comment: **1)** above should be included in the original post (at least to be readable) **2)** it seems still incomplete - what is Arraylist_object and, more important, its content - should also be part of the post **3)** print out `Arraylist_object.get(f).patient_ID` in the inner loop to verify it (using a debugger would be much more efficient)

Comment: Dear i added what required in the post please check