# Java util logger: custom formatter only works for some levels

Tags: java, logging

I have made a custom formatter for the java.util logger, implemented as below

```
logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
sb = new StringBuffer();
try {
  Handler handler = new FileHandler("xx.log");
  handler.setFormatter(new CustomFormatter());
  logger.addHandler(handler);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

 private class CustomFormatter extends Formatter {
    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
      String msg = record.getMessage();
      sb.append(msg);
      System.out.print(sb.toString());
      return sb.toString();
    }
  }
```

Running the following code:

```
logger.finest(msg);
logger.finer(msg);
logger.fine(msg);
logger.config(msg);
logger.info(msg);
logger.warning(msg);
logger.severe(msg);
logger.log(new LogRecord(Level.FINE, msg));
```

Only info, warning, and severe work. the other methods run but return nothing to console, and write nothing to the log file. I need to implement at least 4 logging levels, but only the 3 work.

What is happening to log,config,fine,finer, finest? How do I get them to use my formatter? Or how do I pass the level to the formatter?

Comment: Could you try to add `logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);` ?

Comment: may be java.util.logging has a root logger that defaults to Level.INFO.see here , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315699/why-are-the-level-fine-logging-messages-not-showing

Comment: that fixed it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set the `Level` of logging with [setlevel(Level)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#setLevel(java.util.logging.Level))

> Set the log level specifying which message levels will be logged by
>   this logger. **Message levels lower than this value will be discarded**.

In your case as you are interested in all levels, it would be :

```
logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

Comment: 0
down vote

Doesn't one have to set the logging level in the logger *and* in the handler?