# FINE and below messages not appearing when using ConsoleHandler logging

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

Despite consulting the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315699/why-are-the-level-fine-logging-messages-not-showing), my Logger will never show messages of level `FINE` and below.

```
Logger root = Logger.getLogger("");
root.setLevel(Level.FINEST); // I have also tried Level.ALL
    
// Test messages
root.severe("Severe");
root.warning("Warning");
root.info("Info");
root.fine("Fine");
root.finer("Finer");
root.finest("Finest");
```

The code produces the following output.

```
Nov 27, 2021 4:28:45 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
SEVERE: Severe
Nov 27, 2021 4:28:45 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
WARNING: Warning
Nov 27, 2021 4:28:45 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
INFO: Info
```

I have tried updating the logging.properties file to set the `ConsoleHandler`'s level to `ALL` and `FINEST`, but that does not change my results. How do I actually change the level of my logger?

My `logging.properties`:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level= ALL

java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = %h/java%u.log
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 50000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 1
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.XMLFormatter

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Comment: Please provide your logging configuration also - content of the `logging.properties` file or configuration done in the code. Most likely you did not set proper logging level for the `ConsoleHandler`. By default, it is set to `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO` in the `logging.properties` file provided with JDK. Look at the `Editing the handler Level` section in the SO answer you referred to how to do this.

Comment: Where is logging.properties located?  Are you sure it’s in the same JRE or JDK that you are using when you run the program?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [test program to print the logger tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882648/logging-not-showing/44888306#44888306) and post the console output.  This will prove if your static configuration file is actually being used at runtime.

It shouldn't be a problem for the root logger but you should declare your logger as static final so it doesn't get garbage collected and you lose all of your progmatic changes.