# Why does Jenkins log file size grows so much?

Tags: logging, jenkins

I'm having a problem on my digital ocean server. Jenkins stops working after my droplet runs out of disk space. And what is causing this is the jenkins.log file that's growing to 15 GB in a couple of days. This is also causing the OS to lose the swap file.

How can I debug the logging in Jenkins? Could this problem has to do with a bad implementation or configuration of my jobs?

I've seen this is a problem for others, and normally people recommend [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logfilesizechecker+Plugin) which I don't understand much, why would I want to kill my build if things are going ok? Or does a build only logs when something goes wrong? Can the logging been disabled?

EDIT -> I've already changed the log level, I think that might be enough for solving my problem. But the main question remains. What can be the cause of such a terrible amount of logs (15GB) in a couple of days.
[image]

Comment: [Google](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging)?

Comment: @StephenKing What's that? A Jenkins plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the *contents* of the logs files?

Most likely you're coming across this [mDNS-related logging bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31719839/234938) in Jenkins.