# JUL wrong caller?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I try to configure logging programatically. I load the informations from a .properties-file. To configure the logger i call:

```
final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(cat);
logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
logger.log(Level.ALL,"Test");
```

It prints `Test`, so this part works. This is the stacktrace inside `getLogger`:
[image: Trace of create logger]

Later, when the logger will get used, the level is INFO.
[image: Later use]

It looks like there are different logger contexts. How to merge?

Comment: When you want to have just 1 logger, you could make it `static` and use it via that reference but usually you'd configure log settings more like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307648/change-global-setting-for-logger-instances

Comment: Statics are instanticated on classload, i like to configure before classload.

Comment: I don't know where the code in your example is but it won't execute before the class it's in gets loaded either

Comment: They are different classes, one class loads the configuration (called ConfigImpl.java) and the other class reference the static logger (freemarker.cache.TemplateCache).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! The Garbage-collector removes the logger meanwhile and drops the configured value.