# Java Logger is not logging to output in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, logging, netbeans

I'm starting a Java project using Maven in Netbeans. I wrote some code to do logging with the Logger class. However, the logging doesn't seem to work. At the beginning of my program, I run:

```
Logger.getLogger(ProjectMainClass.class.getName()).setLevel(LOG_LEVEL);
Logger.getLogger(ProjectMainClass.class.getName()).log(LOG_LEVEL, "Hello Logger");
```

The second line never outputs my message to the output screen in Netbeans.
`System.out.print` statements do show up in the output.

I feel like I need to set some configuration option. I've searched around, but I can't figure it out (in the past I've always debugged with System.out and debugger, but I think the logger is much more powerful (and more confusing)).

Comment: Do you have you log4j in your class path ?

Comment: I don't think so. Is that in Options => Java => Ant => Classpath?

Comment: It depends on how you are running the application . Is it a web app or a main class ?

Comment: although I am using Maven, not Ant.

Comment: just place your log4j.properties in src folder

Comment: I don't have a log4j.properties

Comment: @NullPointerException It looks like the OP is using the standard Logger, not log4j.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199598/using-java-util-logging-to-log-on-the-console may be this post helps u

Comment: Same problem here, what gives

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Java Logging API and if you have a  java class like the next:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import static java.util.logging.Level.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Level[] levels = {
            OFF, SEVERE, WARNING, INFO,
            CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST, ALL
        };
        for (Level level : levels) {
            LOG.setLevel(level);
            LOG.log(level, "Hello Logger");
        }
    }
}
```

You notice that the output is:

```
Jun 7, 2013 6:30:16 PM Main main
SEVERE: Hello Logger
Jun 7, 2013 6:30:16 PM Main main
WARNING: Hello Logger
Jun 7, 2013 6:30:16 PM Main main
INFO: Hello Logger
```

What happens? What about the other levels? What am I doing wrong? Don't worry. Be happy! This is because the default level for Java Logging API is `INFO`. You can find this in the configuration file `logging.properties` in the JRE, e.g.

```
D:\Software\jdk1.6.0_43\jre\lib\logging.properties
```

In this file, we can see the lines:

```
# Default global logging level.
# This specifies which kinds of events are logged across
# all loggers.  For any given facility this global level
# can be overriden by a facility specific level
# Note that the ConsoleHandler also has a separate level
# setting to limit messages printed to the console.
.level= INFO
```

And, as the text indicates, the level for the console handler:

```
# Limit the message that are printed on the console to INFO and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
```

This is the reason why the maximum level of detail in the output is `INFO`. You can change the level in this file or in your code (this is best to not affect the level of other processes), e.g.:

```
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import static java.util.logging.Level.*;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Level[] levels = {
            OFF, SEVERE, WARNING, INFO,
            CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST, ALL
        };


        Logger root = Logger.getLogger("");
        // .level= ALL
        root.setLevel(ALL);
        for (Handler handler : root.getHandlers()) {
            if (handler instanceof ConsoleHandler) {
                // java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
                handler.setLevel(ALL);
            }
        }

        for (Level level : levels) {
            LOG.setLevel(level);
            LOG.log(level, "Hello Logger");
        }
    }
}
```

The output for the last code is:

```
Jun 7, 2013 6:31:13 PM Main main
SEVERE: Hello Logger
Jun 7, 2013 6:31:13 PM Main main
WARNING: Hello Logger
Jun 7, 2013 6:31:13 PM Main main
INFO: Hello Logger
Jun 7, 2013 6:31:13 PM Main main
CONFIG: Hello Logger
Jun 7, 2013 6:31:13 PM Main main
FINE: Hello Logger
Jun 7, 2013 6:31:13 PM Main main
FINER: Hello Logger
Jun 7, 2013 6:31:13 PM Main main
FINEST: Hello Logger
Jun 7, 2013 6:31:13 PM Main main
ALL: Hello Logger
```

**EDIT**

You can also use another file `logging.properties` whith the desired level adding an argument to the virtual machine:

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\mylogging.properties"
```

Comment: you have to call logger.setHandler(new ConsoleHandler()) in some place ,dont you?