# Trying to figure out how to minimize ehcache logs (n.s.e.constructs.web.filter.Filter)

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, ehcache

I'm new with using ehcache and I'm guessing that these debug messages I have been receiving is coming from an open-source project I am using. The logs are growing like wildfire and I wish I could find a way to minimize them. These are the types of log messages that I am receiving each time a page reload occurs.

```
08:33:19.626 [http-8080-6] DEBUG n.s.e.constructs.web.filter.Filter - Request Headers: host -> my.application.com: connection -> keep-alive: cache-control -> max-age=0: accept -> */*: if-none-match -> W/"17227-1367868490000": if-modified-since -> Mon, 06 May 2013 19:28:10 GMT: user-agent -> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36: referer -> my.application.com/f/u25l1s4/normal/render.uP: accept-encoding -> gzip,deflate,sdch: accept-language -> en-US,en;q=0.8: cookie -> SESS29f919b3f2c84b3e362ffe4e56d595bd=4b4e6edlaadlhfa6gu8lj66u11; __utma=90227742.1696363642.1351091807.1375806239.1376082782.23; __utmz=90227742.1375806239.22.5.utmcsr=...|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/get-help/guides-faqs/emailcalendar/office-365-configuration; BIGipServertest_portal_pool=973860009.36895.0000; __utma=124793366.1826473631.1376577744.1376577744.1376580642.2; __utmb=124793366.37.9.1376580778696; __utmc=124793366; __utmz=124793366.1376577744.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)

08:33:19.627 [http-8080-6] DEBUG n.s.e.c.web.filter.CachingFilter - Thread http-8080-6  has been marked as visited.

08:33:19.627 [http-8080-6] DEBUG net.sf.ehcache.Cache - Cache: SimplePageCachingFilter store hit for GET/ResourceServingWebapp/rs/backbone/0.9.2/backbone-0.9.2.min.jsnull

08:33:19.629 [http-8080-6] DEBUG n.s.e.constructs.web.filter.Filter - Request Headers: host -> my.application.com: connection -> keep-alive: cache-control -> max-age=0: accept -> */*: if-none-match -> W/"17227-1367868490000": if-modified-since -> Mon, 06 May 2013 19:28:10 GMT: user-agent -> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36: referer -> my.application.com/f/u25l1s4/normal/render.uP: accept-encoding -> gzip,deflate,sdch: accept-language -> en-US,en;q=0.8: cookie -> SESS29f919b3f2c84b3e362ffe4e56d595bd=4b4e6edlaadlhfa6gu8lj66u11; __utma=90227742.1696363642.1351091807.1375806239.1376082782.23; __utmz=90227742.1375806239.22.5.utmcsr=...|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/get-help/guides-faqs/emailcalendar/office-365-configuration; BIGipServertest_portal_pool=973860009.36895.0000; __utma=124793366.1826473631.1376577744.1376577744.1376580642.2; __utmb=124793366.37.9.1376580778696; __utmc=124793366; __utmz=124793366.1376577744.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

Any suggestions as to what I should do or look at?

Thanks,
Laura

Comment: What framework are you using for loggin? log4j? Can you shared some lines of your `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml`?

Comment: It's a spring framework and the open source project I am using is uPortal. Because it involves portlets also, there are log4j property files everywhere. I had grepped for DEBUG and I replaced every instance of DEBUG with WARN. However, it could be some .jar file in a lib directory that has it also. Someone told me of one lib file xmlsec-1.4.3.jar that is a dependency, which has the DEBUG setting enabled. So I unjarred it, modified it and repackaged it and that didn't fix it...so it could be any one of a hundred jar files that may have this setting...which worries me.

Comment: Anyway, I was hoping for a higher level way of suppressing it..like perhaps a Tomcat setting.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the Tomcat's level is more verbose. Tomcat use [`java.util.logging` API (JUL)](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging), so you have a `logging.properties` file (in the application or in the `conf` directory of Tomcat).

In those files, you can find lines some the next.

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter
```

Changes to the desired level.

See also:

- [Java Logging API and How To Use It](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/logging.jspx)
- [Java Logger is not logging to output in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16994384/870248)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It turns out that the open-source project was missing a file on the minor release and it was fixed in the latest release. But, this may be a good idea to have more control on the Tomcat level

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://issues.jasig.org/browse/RESSERV-48). It happens because logback is the logging implementation but no logback configuration has been added. In fact log4j configuration has been incorrectly added. It seems to only affect version 1.0.29 of the resource-server-webapp.

It has been fixed in 1.0.30 so my recommendation would be to upgrade to that as it looks like a safe update. However, if you can't then you just need to add a logback.xml configuration into the war. You can see the one that gets added in the updated version in [the pull request](https://github.com/auxepaul/resource-server/commit/36ec550a89f8835487e4ac0afa6207ba4b959f5e).